# MySQL - search for formatted conbinations of column values

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a database where a table has, amongst other, two columns: `group` and `article`. Both are `int` but is always formatted before shown to the user:

- The `group` is always shown as 2 digits, with leading zeros if
  needed.
- The `article` is always shown as 4 digits, with leading zeros
  if needed.
- The `group` and `article` are separated with a dash -

**Example**:
An item with `group = 1` and `article = 23` will be shown to the user as `01-0023`.

**Moving on**.
I have a php-script in which as user can search for an article. The user will of course write the article in the formatted way. The script I have today, uses regular expressions to separate a search for an article from free-text and then isolates the `group` and `article` from each other before searching the database.

My question is, is it possible to pass the formatted string (e.g. 01-0023) in the query instead and if so, how would I manipulate the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a comparison to a value shown to the user, you can do:

```
where `group` = substring_index(@Group_Article, '-', 1) + 0 AND
      `article` = substring_index(@Group_Article, '-', -1) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/21241/0)**

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('01-0023', 2) AS UNSIGNED) AS `Group`
      ,CAST(RIGHT('01-0023',4) AS UNSIGNED) AS `Article`
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table like that

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `group` `group` INT(2) ZEROFILL,
CHANGE COLUMN `article` `article` INT(4) ZEROFILL;
```

Create a view

```
CREATE VIEW `v_my_table` AS 
SELECT id,article,`group`,CONCAT(`group`,"-",`article`) AS conbined FROM my_table;
```

Use your view for select statements

```
mysql> select * from v_my_table;
+----+---------+-------+----------+
| id | article | group | conbined |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|  1 |    0005 |    03 | 03-0005  |
|  2 |    0005 |    03 | 03-0005  |
|  3 |    0021 |    12 | 12-0021  |
|  4 |    0212 |    55 | 55-0212  |
|  5 |    2113 |    04 | 04-2113  |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: It's an already existing database that's used on different UIs (access, ruby, python, php). I'm not able to alter anything in it. I need to use it as is.