# MySQL - ranking results based on parameters in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649944/mysql-search-for-formatted-conbinations-of-column-values) I found out how to split up my search string '01-0023' and search two columns. Now I want to also add results from a third column `description`. However, I want data that results from the (group, article) to show first (i.e. ranked higher/more relevant). How is this possible?

**Original query:** `SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE group= substring_index('@search_string', '-', 1) + 0 AND article= substring_index('@search_string', '-', -1) + 0`

**New query:**  `SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE (group= substring_index('@search_string', '-', 1) + 0 AND article= substring_index('@search_string', '-', -1) + 0) OR description LIKE '%@search_string%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ARTICLES 
WHERE (group= substring_index('@search_string', '-', 1) + 0 
    AND article= substring_index('@search_string', '-', -1) + 0) 
OR description LIKE '%@search_string%'
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN (group= substring_index('@search_string', '-', 1) + 0 
        AND article= substring_index('@search_string', '-', -1) + 0) THEN 1
    WHEN description LIKE '%@search_string%' THEN 2 END ASC
```

Comment: It works fine when if I change `ORDER BY SELECT CASE` to `ORDER BY CASE`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the logic to the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ARTICLES
ORDER BY (`group` = substring_index('@search_string', '-', 1) + 0) DESC,
         (`article` = substring_index('@search_string', '-', -1) + 0) DESC
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I want the results based on group and article, which will be 1 row, to be shown first, and then I want any results that comes from the `description`.